# Asset URL's invalid

Tags: assets, url, config

I have followed the points set out in the Craft Docs relating to environmentVariables, making sure to include `'*' => array()` before other config arrays. Here is my `craft/config/general.php`:

return array(

```
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'defaultImageQuality' => 49,
    ),

    'dev.sitename' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://dev.sitename/',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/Users/adammenczykowski/Sites/Sitename/sitename/public/',
            'baseUrl' => 'http://dev.sitename/',
        )
    ),

    'sitename' => array(
        'devMode' => false,
        'siteUrl' => 'http://sitename.youi.design/',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'basePath' => '/home/forge/sitename/public/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'http://sitename/',
        )
    )

);
```

Asset sources reference the basePath when configuring the `File System Path` like so:

```
{basePath}images/
```

Yes, the folder exists. I have been using `pwd` and copying the result into the respective `general.php` setting.

However, when I try to update asset indexes, I get the popup:

```
The path of your source "SVG" appears to be invalid.`
```

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Running `Craft CMS 2.6.2797`

Answer (score 2):

2 factors were at play here:

- The HTML-Cache plugin was clouding my development analysis by not showing me updated templated entries.
- I had set the local path wrong, it should have respected my Vagrant VM file structure, `/home/vagrant/Sites/Sitename/sitename/public`

Disabling the html cache plugin and repairing the `basePath` environment variable did the trick.

Comment: Good stuff, Adam. We all get trapped by such things and do  -- on the first time.... Caches can really muddy waters also, similar truth. Glad you posted, for others to find.